# How to stop ajax request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I'm using jquery for making ajax requests

```
$.ajax(
    url: "http://someurl.org",
    success: function() { ... }
);
```

How can I manually stop my particular ajax request?

Comment: possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/446594/kill-ajax-requests-using-javascript-using-jquery

Comment: ok, thank you. I failed to find it after some hard googling

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The `$.ajax()` method returns an object that could be used to do that:

```
var xhr = $.ajax(
    url: "http://someurl.org",
    success: function() { ... }
);
```

and then later when you want to stop the request:

```
xhr.abort();
```

Comment: ajax can be stopped from being initiated, but once its made its not possible to stop it...

Comment: @JIA, you can abort the AJAX request in the browser but of course if it has already hit the web server, that's a whole different story. The web server will continue to execute the request. It's just that since the browser aborted the request the web server will send the response to the void.

Comment: @DarinDimitrov so it means that if an already initiated request is aborted using the `.abort` method it will not be catered for at the client side ...

Comment: @JIA, that will depend when you call the abort method.

Answer (score 3):

ajax requests are HTTP transactions once made cannot be stopped. You can stop ajax request from being initiated but not kill the already made request.

Comment: XHR requests, like all HTTP requests, can be aborted while underway. Whether a certain Ajax library exposes this functionality is a different issue.