# How to pass MVC view model into AJAX call with AntiForgeryToken

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, antiforgerytoken

The code below is working for me, but I'm trying to find a way to read all values from the form instead of having to re-create the view model in JavaScript (vm is the name of the parameter of the object).

I tried to serialize the form and pass it in, but maybe my syntax is incorrect.

**Any suggestions?**

```js
$.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    dataType: "json",
    url: "/post-details-save",
    data: addAntiForgeryToken({
        vm: ({
            Id: $("#PostImageDetails_Id").val(),
            Title: $("#PostImageDetails_Title").val(),
            Description: $("#PostImageDetails_Description").val(),
            CopyrightOwner: $("#PostImageDetails_CopyrightOwner").val(),
            CopyrightUrl: $("#PostImageDetails_CopyrightUrl").val(),
            SourceName: $("#PostImageDetails_SourceName").val(),
            SourceUrl: $("#PostImageDetails_SourceUrl").val(),
            SourceLicenseType: $("#PostImageDetails_SourceLicenseType").val()
        })
    }),
    success: postDetailsSaveSuccess,
    error: postDetailsSaveError
});
```

Comment: You can use `.$ajaxSetup`. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14063248/intercepting-a-jquery-ajax-request-to-insert-additional-variables) for an example. Then you can intercept the request before you send it, and then add your antiforgerytoken.

Comment: Are you using MVC.NET?

Comment: Yes MVC with Razor views

Answer (score 0):

### Confirm Form Setup

```
@using (Html.BeginForm("ActionName", "ControllerName", FormMethod.Post, new { @id = "formID" }))
```

I have done similar stuff with submitting forms in partial views.

Basically, you need to confirm that your html form is set up correctly:

**The AntiForgeryToken**

```
@Html.AntiForgeryToken()
```

**Data Fields**

Could look something like the following with the name attribute being important.

```
<input type="hidden" name="ApproveUserID" id="ApproveUserID" value="@Model.ApproveUserID" />
```

**AJAX The Form**

If your form is set up correctly like explained above, you will be able to submit the data via AJAX with something similar to the JS below.

```
var form = $("#formID");
$.ajax({
    url: form.attr('action'),
    type: form.attr('method'),
    data: form.serialize(), // data to be submitted
    success: function (response) {
        if (response == "Success") {
            //DO SUCCESS STUFF
        } else
        {
            //DO FAILURE STUFF
        }
    },
    error: function () {
            //DO ERROR STUFF
    }
});
```

---

**Pro Tip:**

You can always expand the data you send by placing

```
var formData = form.serialize();
```

Into a variable and expanding it from there.

Good Luck.

Comment: Your suggestion is not working for me, it does not reach the server side function at all (I'm getting 500 status)... I'm using jQuery v3.1.1 and my AJAX function look like: public async Task<JsonResult> PostDetailsSave(PostImageDetailsViewModel vm)